# How can I obtain just one JSON object with the three models information combined?

Tags: django, serialization, django-models

How can I pass the foreign key values from my model to my serialised json object?

Now I have this three models,

```
class Fleet(models.Model):
    fleet_id = models.IntegerField('Id flota', primary_key=True, unique=True)
    fleet_name = models.CharField('Nombre flota', max_length=20, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fleet_name + ' ' + str(self.fleet_id)

class Device(models.Model):
    dev_eui = models.CharField(max_length=16, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    producer = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    dev_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)

    fleet_id = models.ForeignKey(Fleet, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dev_eui

class DevData(models.Model):
    data_uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid1, editable=False)
    frequency = models.IntegerField()
    data_1 = models.FloatField()
    data_2 = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    dev_eui = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #hay que saber porque añade _id

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dev_eui
```

And what I'm doing is call my `view` function in my `JS` code to obtain some data like this.

```
def getData(request):
    ctx = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        select = int(request.POST['Select'])

        data = DevData.objects.order_by('dev_eui','-data_timestamp').distinct('dev_eui')
        nodes = Device.objects.all()
        fleets = Fleet.objects.all()
        data = loads(serializers.serialize('json', data))
        nodes = loads(serializers.serialize('json', nodes))
        fleets = loads(serializers.serialize('json', fleets))

        ctx = {'Data':data, 'Nodes':nodes, 'Fleets':fleets}

    return JsonResponse(ctx)
```

And inside my `js` file I filter it with some `if else` conditionals.

This works well, but I'm sure I can do it directly in my view but I don't know how. How can I obtain just one `JSON` object with the three models information combined?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Django's built-in serializer doesn't provide that functionality out of the box. You can use [**DRF Serializer**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) which is a great library

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom serializer like this:

```
from django.core.serializers.json import Serializer

class CustomSerializer(Serializer):

    def end_object(self, obj):
        for field in self.selected_fields:
            if field == 'pk':
                continue
            elif field in self._current.keys():
                continue
            else:
                try:
                    if '__' in field:
                        fields = field.split('__')
                        value = obj
                        for f in fields:
                            value = getattr(value, f)
                        if value != obj and isinstance(value, JSON_ALLOWED_OBJECTS) or value == None:
                            self._current[field] = value

                except AttributeError:
                    pass
        super(CustomSerializer, self).end_object(obj)
```

Then use it like this

```
serializers = CustomSerializer()
queryset = DevData.objects.all()
data = serializers.serialize(queryset, fields=('data_uuid', 'dev_eui__dev_eui', 'dev_eui__fleet_id__fleet_name'))
```

I have wrote an article regarding serializing nested data [here](https://ruddra.com/posts/django-serialize-foreignkey-m2m-property-instance-fields/). You can check that out as well.

Comment: Thank you very much!! One question, if I want all the fields inside `serializers.serialize()`,  I need to write it all? Or there is an option like "__all__"?

Comment: unfortunately, no. You have to write all the fields via `__`. atleast for this override. But you can modify above implementation to get all the fields by using `obj.__class__.get_fields()`.